# Are the games the same as the books?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

I don't know if this can be asked here. But I just finished the AC series of games and I really enjoyed the characters especially Ezio. Are the books just copies of the games with more character development(if even) Or do they have more story and little reference to the games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read the new books, but **the Ezio novels follow the plot of the games pretty much exactly**, to the point that some of the dialogue from the games is repeated in the books.  Even the fight during the tutorial mission is shown in "Renaissance".

However, there is one major exception - Desmond and Abstergo are never mentioned.  The stories are told as if Ezio is the main character, rather than Desmond experiencing Ezio's life through the Animus.

Comment: So, if I have played through the games. There is no real point of me going into a shop buying the series and reading them as I passed the games?

Comment: That is pretty much correct.  You won't learn anything new.

Comment: May I ask have you read the Metro 2033 book and played the game by any chance?

Comment: Can't help you there, sorry.

Comment: Damn, didn't want to create a new thread a well. I'll give it a read!

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec  I have read the Metro 2033 book. It's freaking great. If you have played the game, you know the overarching story, but the places, people and interactions are different. It's worth a read for the atmosphere alone.

Comment: Thanks man. I got a 4 hour bus trip now with Metro 2033 on the Kindle!

Comment: I personally think the books add more to the story, there will be some extra dialogue in the books and it also explores more of ezio's love life which you will miss in the games